# I have a drop down menu now how to create submenu inside one link using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am very new to css trying to learn new language,  I have a dropdowm which i had done using css and html now how to create a submenu into it on hover  over one link

Check my code till now what i did :

```css
.nav-collapse .nav li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #7281a1;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 25px 15px 26px 30px;
}

.nav-collapse .nav>li {
  margin-left: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-collapse .nav li a#home-nav {
  background: url('../images/home.png') 3px center no-repeat;
}

.nav-collapse .nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #7281a1;
}

ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #8248ac;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

ul.dropdown:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid #8248ac;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: 20px;
  top: -10px;
}

ul.dropdown li {
  border-top: 1px solid #f7f8f9;
}

ul.dropdown li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

ul.dropdown li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 7px !important;
}

.nav-collapse .nav>li:hover ul.dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">

    <li>
      <a id="home-nav" href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub-dropdown</a></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So when user hover on Menu dropdown should come and when user hover in dropdown sub-drop down should come

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I got what i need Thanks!! @Cristina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should hide the sub-menu and show it when you hover on the link, just like the first dropdown

add this code to your css file

```
ul.dropdown li ul {
  display:none;
}

ul.dropdown li.dropdown:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
```

**See working snippet:**

```css
.nav-collapse .nav li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #7281a1;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 25px 15px 26px 30px;
}

.nav-collapse .nav>li {
  margin-left: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-collapse .nav li a#home-nav {
  background: url('../images/home.png') 3px center no-repeat;
}

.nav-collapse .nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #7281a1;
}

ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #8248ac;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

ul.dropdown:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid #8248ac;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: 20px;
  top: -10px;
}

ul.dropdown li {
  border-top: 1px solid #f7f8f9;
}

ul.dropdown li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

ul.dropdown li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 7px !important;
}

.nav-collapse .nav>li:hover ul.dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -2px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #8248ac;
  display: none;
}

ul.dropdown li.dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">

    <li>
      <a id="home-nav" href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub-dropdown</a></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The following code is not floating the submenu in the right side and the only text is becoming invisible the white background is still there

Comment: @PiyushSeofaceup thats because i used visibility.. see my edit .. now i used display instead

Comment: @PiyushSeofaceup do you want the whole menu to be on the right of the page or something else?

Comment: Only the submenu part on hover to the right side for example when user hover in  dropdown ,  "sub-dropdown" float in the right side @Chiller

Comment: Wonderfull!! I want the same , Thanks a lot !! But what changes you had made in earlier code